# Extract xml element and sub element in xmlObject

Tags: java, xml

```
<Personal isUpdated="1">
<Legal_Name>
    <Country>France</Country>
    <First_Name>.....</First_Name>
    <Last_Name>...</Last_Name>
</Legal_Name>
<Citizenship >
    <Citizenship_Status_ID>yyy</Citizenship_Status_ID>
</Citizenship>
<Gender>1</Gender>
<Date_of_Birth >1988-07-31</Date_of_Birth>
<Country_of_Birth>xxxx</Country_of_Birth>
<City_of_Birth >xxxx</City_of_Birth>
<Marital_Status>C</Marital_Status>
<Nationality>xxxx</Nationality>
<Last_Medical_Exam_Date >xxxx</Last_Medical_Exam_Date>
```

I want to extract element exemple (.....) in xmlObject map and and the element  added to the xmlObject map.

**constraint** : i want to do the extract without specific name of xml tags and the format of the xml file change so we haven't always the same structure of xml file. so i want a géneric solution.

Any help please.

Comment: No idea of what you are asking. You need a specific method that will parse the XML and hold its inner structure? What is your code so far? Did you used Java's existing functionality?

Comment: for parsing xml i use xmlBeans (XmlObject.Factory.parse(xmlfile);) i want to know if there's existing functionality in java that allow me to do an extraction without konwing the structure of xml. that why i asked for généric solution

Comment: Correct me if I get it wrong, but the only way to parse unknown XML trees, is to focus on the only commonality between them: `Node` and `Child`. Regardless of how many nested layers an XML has, it will always contain parents and children.

Comment: Yes all what you said is correct, but i don't a have tag names of this xml file so i want get all this xml element of the xml tree in a list, for that  i i have name of node but i haven't the name tag of children and the internal sturctre change always so how can i parse it and stock element by element in a list?

Comment: Exhaustively iterate until there are no other children.